# TemporalType in case of setParameter(String name, Object value)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

When in a JPQL-Query I use `setParameter(String name, Object value)` instead of `setParameter(String name, Date value, TemporalType temporalType)` ...

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select name from person where createdAt > :d");
q.setParameter("d", new java.util.Date());
```

... which `TemporalType` Hibernate internally will use for `java.util.Date`? `DATE`, `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`?

And which would be used for `java.time.LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Follow this link : https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/TemporalType

Comment: Depends what you want to persist ... the date + time, just the date ? just the time?

Comment: @BillyFrost when I use setParameter(String name, Object value) I cannot specify that - the question is, what Hibernate will use in this case ...

Comment: Since the JPA spec has explicitly provided a method for you to use for java.util.Date where you have to specify that extra argument, it is simply left to the JPA provider what to pick for you (and you take the consequences).

Comment: @BillyFrost yes - and this was the question: what does Hibernate pick?

Comment: and why cant you just try it ??

Answer (score 0):

It should be DATE when you are using java.utils.Date. Sadly as far as I know LocalDate is still not supported by hibernate so you will have to use date timestamp or time depending on which suits you better in the current situation. 
You can read more about it [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html).

Comment: Since LocalDate is part of the JPA 2.2 spec then all JPA providers that claim to support the JPA 2.2 spec should "support" it. But that doesnt mean there will be a new TemporalType added for it ... since those types simply represent the database type.